# What is the difference between document.querySelector('#button') and document.getElementById('button')

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, queryselector

I am. A beginner of JavaScript and am confused that what is the difference between `document.querySelector('#button')` and `document.getElementById('button')`?

For example,

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
```

And

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
```

Give the same result. Then what is the difference between them?

I know that `querySelector()` returns the first element matching, but IDs are already unique...

Comment: https://whatabouthtml.com/difference-between-getelementbyid-and-queryselector-180

Answer (score 0):

Query selector will select the first element in the Dom which matches the query, it can be an ID, tag, class etc.
getElementById will select the ID

Comment: ID's are already unique...

Answer (score 0):

They pretty much do the same thing. It's down to opinion and none is better than the other.

Comment: Then why is there an existence of both of them..

Comment: Well, let me rephrase. querySelector returns a HTMLElement and getElementById returns just an Element. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

In most use cases, this is not an issue, but sometimes you may want one over the other